# When I run my netbeans code for user login it shows an error saying " Login.DB_Opreration has no main method"

Tags: java, netbeans-8

```
    package Login;

import java.sql.*;
import static java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection;

public class DB_Operation {
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;


    public Connection getConnection(){
        try{
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/s_user";
            String user="root";
            String pass="";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Error"+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                        System.out.println("Error"+ ex.getMessage());


        }
        finally{
            return conn;
        }
    }
    public ResultSet searchQuery(String sql) throws SQLException{
     try{

         getConnection();
         st=conn.createStatement();
         rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

     }   
     catch(SQLException ex){
         System.out.println("Error"+ex.getMessage());
     }
     return rs;
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to connect the Netbeans Project to the database in Wamp server. 
Under the package Login, I've created a JavaClass called DB_Operation which has the code for the database connection.
Although there are no errors displayed in the code there is a compilation error saying "Class "Login.DB_Operation" does not have a main method"

Comment: where do you run this code in? you can call `searchQuery(String sql)` method in main method. most of java programs begin from main method.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried to run the project / file. A file won't run if there is no main method, same for a project and a main class. If you're trying to run the file you'll need a main method. The main method is the method that's defined to be called at the start of an application. Without it, there is no place to start running. It looks like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // call the other necessary methods to run the program.
}
```

Also, considering you have conn as a field which getConnection() assigns and you call getConnection() without assigning it to a variable; there's no need to return a connection, you should make that return void.

You can try calling getConnection() from the main method then (you'll have to make it a static method).

Comment: getConnection() is called under the try block which is a part of searchQuery(). Should I write the whole try-catch block in the main method?

Comment: The SQLException that can spawn in searchQuery() is already caught in searchQuery(), so you don't have to throw it.

Comment: Either you don't have the try-catch in searchQuery() and throw an exception, in which case you need the try-catch to call searchQuery(). Or if you have the try-catch in searchQuery() you don't need to throw an exception so you don't need try-catch to call searchQuery(), but there's no need to have two try-catch blocks.